# How to make text of image editor in website? platform .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I show many editors in websites like stackoverflow and w3school.

i want to develop that type of editor in my website.

tell me how can i develop that text editor. where i can put any language code.

and also formatting it like stackoverflow.

and can i put picture directly pasted in that editor .. if i want to show any
screen shot of any coding or design.

free editors required.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *use* an editor that is capable of adding an image to editable text such as the one here on SO, look into [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).  If you want to develop your own, TinyMCE is open source and would make a good start.

Comment: But. they all are paid editors. if i used them into my website. they i am going to pay. .them. right or wrong?

Comment: No- if you don't have anything against open-source, they're both completely free under variants of GPL/LGPL.

Comment: then What is the commercial licence ?

Comment: TinyMCE has no commercial license.  CKEditor offers a non-copyleft commercial license only for institutions that are prohibited, for whatever reason, from using free open source code.